# thumbnails are getting clipped down, want to resize instead

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I am working on a pre-built theme, and it is clipping the thumbs off. It looks like it is happening in functions.php. I already checked the media and it is not checked. I want to achieve a resizing instead.
The site is the-carstore.info

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to change the wordpress default thumbnail size at any time. Login to your wordpress and go to Settings->media and use the right options or change size of thumbnail with the crop option unchecked.

Then use this plugin to regenerate the thumbnails

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Or if it still doesn't work, that means your theme is overriding some settings.

I would recommend creating a different size manually and then use it in your templates. Its easy. Just add the following code to your functions.php and it will allow you manual control over new size and will add it to the image size list in media upload box (the pop up shadowbox)

```
add_action('admin_head', 'wphd_hide_dashboard', 0);

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'custom-thumb', 300, 9999,false ); //300 pixels wide (and unlimited height, 9999 is large number so as to neglect the height ), cropping set to false
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that's not the problem. I understand how to generate thumbs, and change the size, the problem I am having is the sides of the thumbs are getting chopped off, leaving part of the image missing. I know this is probably too general of a question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is like because image size for thumbnails is defined to have hard crop mode, while you want scaling mode. See [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) in Codex.

You will need to look up size that theme uses for images, and re-register it with different cropping mode.